# Delphi XE8 update 1 - random file not found

Tags: delphi, compilation, file-not-found, delphi-xe8

When I compile a project in XE8 (with update 1), I get frequently a error that a file is missing, although the file is just available. And when I compile again, it is another file that is missing. It seems random. After a few compiles (sometimes more or less) I have build the project. And even at Run (F9) I sometimes get the error that a file is missing.

Like @Andrei Galatyn said at the end of his post, it will be solved when you delete your Android configuration in SDK versions. But I want to be able to develop with Android. What is the real problem?

I couldn't find a solution on the internet yet.

Is there a solution for this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds to me like it might be a hardware problem.

Comment: What is the error message. Is it, "random file not found"? Is it "a file is missing"? Or, by any chance, is there more information that you are concealing from us? This is debugging 101: use the information in front of you. Ignoring the content of error messages is not productive.

Comment: The error message is 'AdSel.pas not found' and after a new compile: 'FormMain.pas not found'. It is no hardware problem I think, the PC is working fine and one of my collegues was having the same problem a while ago. Uncomfortunately he doesnt remember how he fixed that problem.

Comment: It's absolutely going to be an issue with your machine. For sure it will be environmental. Likely a flaky anti-malware tool getting in the way.

Comment: It sounds to me like the classic issue of the long-time broken IDE, reporting that units are missing even though it compiles just fine.

Comment: @David, a bit of a null observation given that a broken IDE (whether by dint of an incorrect/corrupt install or a bug or other issue related to a non-standard install that the IDE engineers in their infinite wisdom failed to anticipate) is just as much an "environmental" issue as anything else on that system be it malware, anti-malware, hard-disk on the verge of a nervous breakdown or a broken install ... these are all "environmental".  ;)

Comment: @Deltics It's the asker you need to tell this to

Comment: @David We got that kind of problem some time ago (with update to XE5 i think) for most (maybe all) of our projects, it is hard to believe that something wrong with all PCs we have. I used small utility to hook file access operations from Delphi, sometimes at random files (without any system) Delphi is trying to access files in wrong folders. Mostly it was subfolder from PlatformSDKs (check my answer for details).

Comment: @Andrei I don't have any difficulty believing that, say, anti malware tools can interfere.

Comment: @David Different PCs, different AV software, some without AV at all. We get problem everywhere when moved to new version of Delphi (from XE3 to XE5 i think). Some PCs are virtual, it is clean Windows with Delphi and very basic tools (MS Office, Notepad++). It looks like bug in Delphi, it sound like bug in Delphi, so i think it is bug in Delphi.

Comment: @David And after upgrade to XE8 we get new problem - now F1 in IDE is enough sometimes to kill Delphi, it crashes without chance to save anything in editors. Of course it could be something outside of Delphi, for example antivirus or maybe aliens. Those kind of aliens who released Delphi with bugs in basic functionality of string helper or library for MD5 hashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have similar problem with Delphi XE8/XE7 at least at 3 different PCs (home PC, notebook, VMW-based virtual machine in office). All PCs are fast, all are SSD-based. Usually i get the error message when trying to build large project, for small projects errors are very rare (but happens time to time anyway).  So i am quite sure that it is problem with Delphi. What i tried:

1. added src/dcu paths as exception to antivirus
2. disabled indexing of files in Windows (Windows 7 x64/Windows 8.1 x64)
3. deleted all SDKs for mobile development in IDE (this step was most usefull in my case).

It doesn't solve the problem for 100%, but now i see that random message only few times per week. I will be glad to see real solution.

Just for information - many errors like "file YYY\XXX.pas not found" where with wrong path to the file, it was path somewhere inside of Android SDK. After deleting of all SDKs (fortunately i need only with Win x32/x64 platforms) i never see such errors anymore.

**Some time ago i sent it to my colleagues:**

Many times i got an sporadic error in Delphi IDE like this:

```
F2039 Could not create output file '.\dcu\FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.dcu'
```

When I just tried to compile again, the problem disappeared but compilation may fail on another file. It was especially annoying when I need to rebuild an large project, for example <...>. Finally I discovered that under some conditions Delphi is trying to access files at wrong path:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\PlatformSDKs\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk\tools\dcu\FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.dcu
```

Instead of

```
C:\M2014\Fellesressurser\felles\FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.dcu
```

All the time when I get the error it was try to access Android SDK folder instead of my application folder.

If you experienced same problem, you can solve it now, just delete Android SDK from Delphi IDE:

- Open “Tools\Options\Environment Options\SDK Manager”
- Select installed SDK (list “SDK versions”)
- Delete it (button “Delete”)

Comment: Can you please tell us your output path configuration? I would have expected something like `.\Win32\dcu\...` and maybe that is the main mistake in your project settings

Comment: @Sir I will check tomorrow, but... even if path is like you suggested. Does it explain sporadic errors? I think if path is wrong, then project will not compile, it shouldn't be like "compilation chances 73%".

Comment: the default is `.\$(Platform)\$(Config)` for both output and dcu. Otherwise you will get some unwanted results - something you describe here. This settings routes the generated output files in different directories for each platform and config

Comment: @Sir Output folders of our projects are configured as ".\dcu" etc, and of course they where created years before Emb released version of IDE with support of mobile platforms, so it is bug of Delphi anyway. But thank you for the hint! I will try to check, if it helps, i will update the answer.

Comment: No, it is not really a bug of Delphi - this behaviour comes from **wrong** project settings. Once you use the correct settings, your compiler will work as expected. Long, long time ago it was normal to hit the women with a wodden club and pull them into the cave ... but that is long, long ago and things have changed dramatically - do you also think this is a bug of the wodden clubs from today? :o)

Comment: @Sir So you think ".\$(Platform)\$(Config)" is correct, but ".\dcu" is wrong? Could you explain why?

Comment: @Sir Your example is not correct i think. It is more like - i always opened the door by hand. One day i installed new door and plumber opened it by ass and shown it works fine. Now i can't open the new door by hand (sometimes),  but you are telling that it is wrong and i should always open the door by ass, then everything goes fine. With Emb it is possible actually, but sorry, i need some explanations.

Comment: Things have changed - Yesterday you had only one supported platform (Win32), today you have seven (Win32,Win64,OSX32,iOS32,iOS64,iOSSimulator,Android32) and each produces sometimes different .dcu files. If you do not build the whole project you maybe end up in linking .dcu files from different platforms. Emba solves this with the different paths for each platform. If you do not use your tool as it is designed you are getting in trouble. If you think it is a bug you should talk to emba ... I do not feel this is a bug, cause I know my tool ;o)

Comment: Deleting Android SDK solved it, but I want to develop with Android still. How can I just use Android plus solve this issue?